# TSQL Select * with alias

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column named "format", which contains rows with strings separated by coma `,` . 
Something like:

-query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  [format]
FROM 
  [mydb].[dbo].[Demand_conditions]
```

-result:

```
format                   <- column's name
,one,two,three,          <- row 1
,paper,cardboard,metal,  <- row 2
```

I select all from a function which gets the values between comas, something like:

```
SELECT * FROM [mydb].[dbo].splitstring(
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        [format]
    FROM 
        [mydb].[dbo].[Demand_conditions]))
```

Which gives me the following result:

UPDATED: THE DISPLAYED COLUMN NAME IS "Name" and I guess is just Management Studio saying: "your column has no name". I want (as I show in the next example) , the COLUMN to be called "format". I DON'T WANT A VALUE IN THE 1st ROW.

```
Name <- No column name
one
two
three
paper
cardboard
metal
```

I need to give a name to the column of the result above:

```
format   <- Column name
one
two
three
paper
cardboard
metal
```

The code for the `splitstring` function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[splitstring] ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for [mydb].[dbo].splitstring?

Comment: @MartinBrown why do you want the code for that function -- it has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I want to see what columns it returns

Comment: You have to give it an alias inside your user defined function `[mydb].[dbo].splitstring()`

Comment: You could just change `(SELECT DISTINCT [format]...` with `(SELECT DISTINCT 'format'+[format]...`

Comment: @Hogan the function code defines the column not the query passed as a parameter

Comment: @Hadi did you read the example code? lol

Comment: @MartinBrown clearly it returns a single column from splitting the first column.

Comment: Why do you HAVE TO go with * ? You already know name of that column

Comment: @Hogan but does it give the column a name?

Comment: @MartinBrown still does not matter -- you don't want to change the function -- you can alias the result (as Gordon does) or add a new row (as Linkan does) -- in both cases changing a general purpose function is the WRONG way to solve the problem.

Comment: @Hogan, why on earth would you want to use a table valued function that is not set up to return column names. Our split function  does, so it is possible. We call our field Value. Then it is easy to simply alias it as whatever you want in the query. Fixing the split function is the best fix. However, he might need to create a new one and name it differently if this function is already extensively used.

Comment: @HLGEM - you are right there is no reason to create a function that way but there is also no reason to believe there is anything wrong with the function here -- just because the OP did not show the function returning a column name does not mean it does not.  AND in general suggesting a user make a change that will cause regression errors across the whole system seems like a really poor idea to me.  I like to suggest fixes that don't break things.  It is easy to do here with an alias or a union.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I updated the question. I need a column name, not a value in the first row. I thought it would be just a simple syntax thing that will allow me to name the column of my results. I tried different combinations, i can't name it.

Comment: SELECT [Name] as [Format] FROM [mydb].[dbo].splitstring(
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        [format]
    FROM 
        [mydb].[dbo].[Demand_conditions]))

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax is probably syntactically invalid, because I doubt that the split string function takes a table as an argument.  Split string functions usually just take strings.  The appropriate method is `apply`.

You can assign column names in table aliases.  I would do this as:

```
SELECT distinct s.format
FROM [mydb].[dbo].[Demand_conditions] dc CROSS APPLY
     ([mydb].[dbo].splitstring(dc.[format])
     ) s(format);
```

The `s(format)` names the column being returned by the `splitstring()` function.

Comment: I don't think that this is what op wants

Comment: @Lamak . . . In what way?

Comment: I gathered that the result of the split string function is missing the first row, which was supposed to be the name of the column. It's a "the column of the name is in the first row" situation (as I understood the question)

Comment: @Lamak . . . I think it is pretty clear that the OP just wants to name the column:  "I need to give a name to the column of the result above".  There is nothing about including the name as a value in the result set.

Comment: I don't think that's what op wants, but well, until the question gets edited I'll abstain on voting on the answers

Comment: I think adding in the CROSS APPLY without explaining it makes this example much harder to understand.  I would also put a `AS` in there to make the table alias more explicit to the OP.

Comment: I copy pasted and get this error in management studio: `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near ')'.`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I updated the question. I need a column name, not a value in the first row.

Comment: @adlisval -- this should give you that are you using this exact code?

Comment: @Hogan I copy pasted and I just replaced the db name and the table name, the syntax is exactly the same. I use management studio 11

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

```
SELECT f.[format] from (
    SELECT * FROM [mydb].[dbo].splitstring(
        (SELECT DISTINCT
            [format]
        FROM 
            [mydb].[dbo].[Demand_conditions])) ) f([format])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
SELECT * FROM [mydb].[dbo].splitstring(
(
  SELECT 'format'
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT
    [format]
  FROM 
    [mydb].[dbo].[Demand_conditions]))
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to add row  having value "format" to output. "Format" should be column name of result set.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev not really, this is what op wants according to the question

Comment: @Lamak Read the question precisely, pay more attention to the phrase *"I need to give a name to the column......"*

Comment: @AndyKorneyev I read it carefully, it's just that you need to pay attention to what op wants, did you look at the results posted?. Sometimes user can't really express themselves in english correctly

Comment: @Lamak what about `format   <- Column name` part of desired output? it definitely indicates that "format" should be column name, not one of result in set.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev yeah, so?. Didi you see the first result?, because op won't receive an actual column with **no name** in SQL Server. That points that s/he wants a first row result that has the column name

Comment: @AndyKorneyev -- clearly it means he want the first row to be the column name in the result set -- I read it as Linkan

Comment: The code needs to be adjusted so that the text in the first select is the same as the column selected in the unioned select. It could probably be done better as a table valued function or a stored procedure though.

Comment: The OP's query would not result in a blank row at the top.  I think he just didn't format his desired result output clearly.  `<-- no column name` indicates that he wants the column to be named.  What use would it be to include the column name in the result set?

Comment: @Jerrad I can think of an infinite number of reasons... lets start with the simplest -- there is an application program that expects a text file where the first row gives the name.

Comment: I get this error when running the code in management studio: `Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I update the question. I need the column name, not a value in the first row.